# I cannot get the same accuracy as Google maps when it comes to distance?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an app which calculate the distance between 2 points. I cannot use the Google Maps API.

I have found the coordinates for each of the markers in the map below.

I am then using the haversine formula to calculate the distance between each points. 
e.g. 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4... etc up to the final point.
I add up these distances to retrieve the total distance for the route.

The problem is Google maps says it is 950-1000 meters, but my app says the length is 1150-1200 meters. I have tried adding in more coordinates, removing coordinates, but I am still getting approximately 200 meters longer route.

Out of curiosity I calculated the distance between the start and end point (the 2 green stars) and this matched the Google Maps distance (998 metres to be exact).

Does this mean Google Maps calculates its distances without the consideration of roads / paths etc.

Here is my code:

```
var coordinates = [
  [1,51.465097,-3.170893,1,0],
  [2,51.465526,-3.170714,0,0],
  [3,51.465853,-3.170526,0,0],
  [4,51.466168,-3.170338,0,0],
  [5,51.466305,-3.170236,0,0],
  [6,51.466534,-3.170157,0,0],
  [7,51.466798,-3.170159,0,0],
  [8,51.467042,-3.170232,0,0],
  [9,51.467506,-3.170580,0,0],
  [10,51.468076,-3.171532,0,0],
  [11,51.468863,-3.172170,0,0],
  [12,51.469284,-3.172841,0,0],
  [13,51.469910,-3.174732,0,0],
  [14,51.470037,-3.174930,0,0],
  [15,51.470350,-3.175091,0,0],
  [16,51.472447,-3.176151,1,0]
];

function distanceBetweenCoordinates() //calculates the distance between each of the coordinates
{
  for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length-1; i++)
  {
      var firstClosestPoint = [0,0,6371];
      var secondClosestPoint = [0,0,6371];
      var lng1 = (coordinates[i][1]);
      var lat1 = (coordinates[i][2]);
      var lng2 = (coordinates[i+1][2]);
      var lat2 = (coordinates[i+1][2]);
      var d = haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
      routeLength = routeLength + d;
 }

return distanceBetweenCoordinatesArray; //returns the array which stores the 2 points and the distance between the 2 points
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my haversine forumla to calculate the distance between 2 points:

Source: [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() //to rad function which is used by the haversine formula
{
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

function haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {  //haversine foruma which is used to calculate the distance between 2 coordinates

  lon1 = lng1;
  lon2 = lng2;
  var R = 6371000; // metres
  var a = lat1.toRad();
  var b = lat2.toRad();
  var c = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
  var d = (lon2-lon1).toRad();

  var a = Math.sin(c/2) * Math.sin(c/2) +
          Math.cos(a) * Math.cos(b) *
          Math.sin(d/2) * Math.sin(d/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `haversine` is not defined

Comment: I just edited the question to include the haversine formula, sorry!

Comment: That is not a function, and now `.toRad()` is not defined.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I ran this through a different implementation of the Haversine formula and got 895m between the end points.

Comment: @sideroxylon what haversine formula did you use?

Comment: @geocodezip I have edited the question to show the full toRad and haversine functions.

Comment: `routeLength` is not defined.

Comment: var routeLength = 0; //global variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have correctly entered your start and end points, this implementation of the haversine formula (which I have tested in the real world) produces a distance of 895m (straight line).

```js
var lt = 51.472447;
var lt1 = 51.465097;
var ln = -3.176151;
var ln1 = -3.170893;
var dLat = (lt - lt1) * Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = (ln - ln1) * Math.PI / 180;
var a = 0.5 - Math.cos(dLat) / 2 + Math.cos(lt1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lt * Math.PI / 180) * (1 - Math.cos(dLon)) / 2;
d = Math.round(6371000 * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)));

$('#distance').html(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="distance"></div>
```

Comment: This works, strange how that other formula didn't work... Thought it was a reliable source! Thanks @sideroxylon!