# how to check if your latitude and longitude are inside a circle?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to the Google Maps API and also mobile development through Phonegap(JavaScript). I am trying to use the current geoLocation obtained through phonegap and use it to determined if that location lies within a circle. Can anyone provide an example of how to perform this? A link to a thread that dealt with this would be useful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to try something and then ask a question explaining what you're having difficulty with

Comment: Let me know if this is oversimplifying your problem, but this seems like a job for the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @david, I am not sure if I need to use the Pythagorean theorem, but I was hoping that the Google Maps API would have a method that allowed me to compare my current Lat Long with the circle's area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your geolocation coords, just calculate the distance from your location to the center of the circle.  If the distance is less than the radius, then your location is inside the circle.

You can see the formula for calculating the distance based on 2 sets of coords [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542133/i-cannot-get-the-same-accuracy-as-google-maps-when-it-comes-to-distance/28543001#28543001)

Comment: Seems like this was more or less what I needed. I wanted to get a clearer picture on the general idea. I think I can use computeDistanceBetween() from the geometry library of Google Maps API to get the distance between the current point and the center.

Comment: Yes, it's just a matter of whether you want to load the additional library and make additional API calls, or prefer to calculate the distance on the client-side.  Either way, it's a pretty easy test if you know the circle center and radius.  Good luck.