# distance and duration between two point selected from google autocomplete using latitude and longitude in androidstudio

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, android-studio, distance

I am trying to get the distance between the points and because the places has no routes names it won't work.

This is the code that I am using

```js
 private void getPrice(String mLocation, String mDestination) {
     String requestUrl= null;
     try {
         requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
           + "mode=driving&"
           +"transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"
           + "origin="+mLocation+"&"
           +"destination="+mDestination+"&"
           +"key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_browser_key);
         Log.e("LINK",requestUrl);
         mService.getPath(requestUrl).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
             @Override public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                 try {
                     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                     JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                     JSONObject object = routes.getJSONObject(0);
                     JSONArray legs = object.getJSONArray("legs");

                     JSONObject legsObject = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                     JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                     String distance_text = distance.getString("text");

                     Double distance_value = Double.parseDouble(distance_text.replaceAll("[^0-9\\\\.]+",""));

                     JSONObject time = legsObject.getJSONObject("duration");
                     String time_text = time.getString("text");
                     Integer time_value = Integer.parseInt(time_text.replaceAll("\\D+",""));

                     String final_calculate = String.format("%s + %s = $%.2f",distance_text,time_text,
                       Common.getPrice(distance_value,time_value));

                     txtCalculate.setText(final_calculate);

                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                 Log.e("ERROR",t.getMessage());
             }
         });
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: there is a way is to use latitude and longitude put first i need to get LatLng from location and destination and use those in my calculation put i don't know how, i have looked to so many examples and nothing works

Comment: Check my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542133/i-cannot-get-the-same-accuracy-as-google-maps-when-it-comes-to-distance/28543001#28543001).  If you have the lat/lng for the start and destination, you can use the Haversine formula to derive the distance.

Comment: If you use autocomplete, I believe you can retrieve a place ID instead of lat,lng. Directions with place ID typically are more precise than directions with lat,lng.